# PostgreSQL. Consequently select results according with specific filters

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, psql

I have a table with users.

User (that uses this programm) can select users by applying different filters. A filters must be applying immediatelly to reduce search time in final `SELECT` and no wasting time.

Currently my code looking like this (Python, not sure that this is working, not tested yet).

The question:

1. How to applying  a filters immediatelly as I get a user input?
2. How to put/pass all actions related to filtering to DB?

```
if only_with_photo:
    cursor.execute('SELECT tg_user_id FROM suers WHERE photo IS NOT NULL')
    users_with_photo = cursor.fetchall()
if only_with_country:
    cursor.execute('SELECT tg_user_id FROM suers WHERE country IS NOT NULL')
    users_with_country = cursor.fetchall()
if only_with_city:
    cursor.execute('SELECT tg_user_id FROM suers WHERE city IS NOT NULL')
    users_with_city = cursor.fetchall()
    
    cursor.execute('SELECT tg_user_id FROM users WHERE tg_user_id IN (users_with_photo) AND tg_user_id                              IN (users_with_country ) AND tg_user_id IN (users_with_city) )
```

Tasks: perform this queries inside psql without using Python or another language?

I tried:

1. CASE `sql = 'SELECT (CASE only_with_photo = 1 THEN (SELECT tg_user_id FROM users WHERE country IS NOT NULL)'  --Subrequest returns more that one result`
2. Variables `/set  only_with_photo := (SELECT tg_user_id FROM users WHERE birthdate IS NOT NULL); --Syntax just now working`

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query with a flexible predicate and put it in a [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) with parameters for each case like the following:

```
SELECT tg_user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE (only_with_photo = 1 AND photo IS NOT NULL)
    OR (only_with_county = 1 AND county IS NOT NULL)
    OR (only_with_city = 1 AND city IS NOT NULL)
```

Etc. But this isn't necessarily the most performant way to do things, though it might be good enough for you case. You'll likely want to add multiple indexes to the users table  based on a few of the most likely combinations of the above predicates.

Comment: Your logic seems to be inverted. Maybe you want `WHERE (allow_without_photo > 0 OR photo IS NOT NULL)  AND (...) ...` And: yes,  it is the most performant; the optimiser will recognise the constant terms and apply short-circuit logic)

Comment: @wildplasser Unless the question was updated since, I must've missed his last line in Python with a joint predicate when I originally wrote this. This will only consolidate the first few queries, and additional or outright different filtering is required for the last part. I'll update my query accordingly, thanks. Surely staging the data differently could result in a more performant solution, but yes if that's not an option, this kind of query is probably near the best one can get in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

> [...] by applying different filters. A filter must be applied immediatelly to reduce search time in final SELECT and no wasting time.

This is not how SQL works. That's a set-based language, where, once the result has been described by the client, all operations are performed at once by the database, in the way that it thinks is the most efficient.

The language offers no feature to interactively refine a resultset. So what you ask for would require building such feature, probably by creating a temporary table for each table, feeding it with the result of the first search, and then deleting rows when criterias are refined.

Instead, you want to gather all of your user's requirement first, then perform a single query that retrieves the data.